# JsonConvert.SerializeObject changes the sort order of fields in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` changes the sorting order of fields in JSON if you call the `.GetProperty` method on the object being serialized in the child thread.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var token = CreateRandomToken();

                _ = typeof(TestObject).GetProperty("Version");

                var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token);

                Console.WriteLine(str);
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static TestObject CreateRandomToken()
        => new TestObject { TokenHash = "123456789", Name = "Name", Version = "123" };

}

public class TestObject
{
    public string TokenHash { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

As a result of executing this code, the following will be displayed on the console:
[image]

The `Version` field is at the beginning of the JSON, not at the end

If we remove

```
_ = typeof(TestObject).GetProperty("Version");
```

- then the sorting of the fields will not change
  or if you call code in the main thread, then the sorting will not change either

[image]

if I decorate my object with the attributes `[JsonProperty (Order = 1)]` then the sorting will not be the same as I indicated in the attributes

How can I fix it? fix without using the attr `[JsonProperty (Order = 1)]`

**Updated**:
We use a JSON string to generate a digital signature if the order of the fields changes the digital signature will not be valid, so the order of the fields is important for me

Comment: Using the attributes is how you fix it. Why is this a problem?

Comment: I would not like to hang attributes to all classes, since there are a lot of these classes and all of them can potentially be used for serialization to JSON

Comment: I would look in to implementing a `DefaultContractResolver` or continue to use `JsonProperty`. Properties do not keep their order unless you specify it. And why should they keep their order by default?

Comment: I meant why is the order a problem?

Comment: we use a JSON string to generate a digital signature if the order of the fields changes the digital signature will not be valid, so the order of the fields is important for me

Comment: Json.Net uses reflection to get the properties of each object and relies on the order returned by .Net iteself.  Here is a [demo program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nx6kTO) with Json.Net removed from the equation, and you can see the same behavior.  I'm guessing that .Net must be caching the property information when it is first retrieved.

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes sense.

Comment: I believe using `JObject.Parse` or similar for the root JSON object it will keep the order found in the JSON. You can then manipulate the object hierarchy manually instead of serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` doesn't guarantee the default order of fields. To specify an explicit sorting, you can use the `DefaultContractResolver`

Thanks [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204153/andy) for the idea!

Implementation of custom `DefaultContractResolver`:

```
 public class OrderedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {           
        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {                                
            return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).OrderBy(p=>p.PropertyName).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
 var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings  {ContractResolver = new OrderedContractResolver()};

 var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the default `JsonSerializer` get properties using `System.Type.GetProperties()`.

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies. (Source  [Type.GetProperties Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-6.0))

In my opinion, you shouldn't care about the order of properties in Json. If the json consumer really need this contract, I think you should review your design.

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array. (Source [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159))