# Why JSON serialize object changes the order of properties in the object

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# object as below:

```cs
public class TxtFileDTO
{
    public object Field01 { get; set; }
    public object Field02 { get; set; }
    public object Field03 { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to convert this, the order of properties is changed. Instead of Field 01, Field 02 is first in order. (I don't want to include a JSON order annotation or anything in my original class.) What could be the reason for this?

I'm doing an operation in the object before the conversion. Removing this line will give the correct result.

```
var valueoffield = txtFileDTO.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(txtFileDTO);
```

Comment: answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70106474/18886549

Comment: I don't want to change the original implementation of the class as suggested in this answer.

Comment: If you are using a library you need to accept that it works in certain ways. Complaining "It does not work like I want it to" will not help. You are ofc free to use another library, implement your own, or contribute a patch if it is open source.

Comment: I'm not using a particular library. It's just a simple Class and the Json convert worked fine until I add a post op. (edited the original question)

Comment: Read the linked answers, there is no particular guaranteed order. So you are relying on undefined behavior, and just about anything could change it. And JsonConvert is not part of the language, so you *are* using a library, probably either newtonsoft or System.Text.Json.